# How to differentiate key event from numpad and barcode reader?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a software that is expected to use a barcode reader. Everything worked fine till a customer started using a new barcode reader and some bindings we got in the numpad keyboard started triggering which did not happened before (we actually tried various barcode readers).

I'm pretty sure it can be fixed from the barcode reader configuration but most of our customers are small shops with no knowledge about stuff like that. So it would be really important for us to fix it from the code.

Here's a mixup code between what I got and what I would like to acomplish, obviouslyI'm ignoring parts of the original code to make it easy readable.

```
$('body').keydown(function(key){
var keyCode = key.keyCode;
switch(keyCode){
    case 96:
    case 97:
    case 98:
    case 99:
    case 100:
    case 101:
    case 102:
    case 103:
    case 104:
    case 105:
    case 110:
        if(not_actually_from_keyboard_but_barcode){
            //step out
        }
        else{
            doNumPadStuff(keyCode);
        }
        break;
});
```

Would appreciate any kind of solution or work around to the problem.

Comment: Look at the event properties and see if anything is different for the reader.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks for the answer. Never though I could get so much information from the event properties. I don't have direct acces to the barcode reader to check it so I'm contacting the customer right now to atleast know the brand and model of the divice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the below helps

The numeric keypad may produce different keycodes depending on the NumLock state.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {    
    /* OPTIONAL: Only if you want other elements to ignore event */
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();



    var keyCode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    debuger //check what keyCode is saying. to get this press f12 to get browser debugger.

    switch(keyCode){
    case 96: //numpad 0
    case 97: //numpad 1
    case 98: //numpad 2
    case 99: //numpad 3
    case 100: //numpad 4
    case 101: //numpad 5
    case 102: //numpad 6
    case 103: //numpad 7 
    case 104: //numpad 8
    case 105: //numpad 9
    case 110: //numpad .

    if(not_actually_from_keyboard_but_barcode){
        //step out
    }
    else{
        doNumPadStuff(keyCode);
    }
    break;
});
```